# Why releasing a record can not be considered as a process?

Tags: future-continuous

Why can't we say" the record will be releasing on 2 th September " if we consider that releasing a record is a process that takes some time.
I know that the correct version is" will be released"

Comment: Who says you can't say that?

Comment: I don't see what the length of time it takes has to do with it.  The record doesn't release anything, the company releases the record.

Comment: @KateBunting - pretty common in commercial circles since at least 1980.

Comment: @KateBunting - I hear court clerks say 'the Jones murder case is sentencing next Tuesday'. I guess it's a kind of occupational way of speaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the active/passive nature of the words "releasing" and "released".

The correct form is "...be released."  This is passive and implies that "{someone} will release the record

The incorrect form " ... be releasing" is active.  It means that the record will release {something?}.

Since records are just pieces of plastic (or just binary codes in an mp3 file), the record can't release something.  [As noted in comments, there is a labile sense of the word "release":  "The record releases Tuesday"  (Compare "I open the door" with "The door opens") But this use seems to me to be jargon and "marketing-speak".]

If you need to indicate that something is progressive it is grammatically correct to say "The record will be being released on Saturday".  But this kind of complex verb phrase with multiple auxiliaries should be avoided if possible, as it is confusing.

Comment: *The record/movie/game **releases** on Friday* has become pretty common.  Sticks-in-the-mud (like myself) still recoil a little at this usage, but I'm not sure it's "incorrect" anymore.

Comment: @Juhasz - toy bricks and shoes as well. 'List of movies releasing next week', 'Roots of Tomorrow, an educational game about sustainable farming, is releasing next week on mobile', 'LEGO Dimensions Wave 3 Expansion Packs Releasing Next Week', 'Tunnel of Terror, releasing next week for Xbox, PC, other platforms', 'Adidas Yeezy 500 High Slate releasing next month'

Comment: Note however that "We'll be releasing the record on Tuesday" is fine, it speaks to some future action.